Why Poll Enrich establishes new connection every time for the Camel SFTP?
Usecase:

Read the filename from topic
Retrieve the file from SFTP
Perform business logic

Sample Route
<from uri= "topic">
<pollEnrich>
<simple> sftp://user:pass?fileName=${body.fileName}&readLock=changed&disconnect=true
</pollEnrich>

Problem: For every kafka message, it creates a new SFTP connection and  the heap memory is growing. Even I've added disconnect option as well but still it's same.
Heap suspects:
3 instances of “org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.SftpConsumer”, loaded by “org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader @ 0xe43dd600” occupy 1,35,59,048 (16.41%) bytes. 

The number of instances will increase for every new message.
